# iCloud: Sync key-value-storage between iOS and Mac. Visual Studio for Mac, C# and Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, icloud, visual-studio-mac

Have a problem. Cant change 'iCloud Key-Value Store' value in Entitlements.plist
It always revert to $(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier) value when i reopen file.
That's why (i think) i cant sync icloud key-values between mac and ios.
Has anyone gotten cross-iOS/Mac synchronization working using Visual Studio for Mac, C# and Xamarin? And how?

Comment: What do you mean by `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)` value? You check the `Key-Value Storage` in the `Entitlements.plist` and when you reopen the `Entitlements.plist`, it revert to uncheck?

Comment: Not unchecked
It reverted to $(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier) (this is placeholder for VS)  value
I try to set equal value for Mac and iOS apps
(bundle ids are different for this apps)

Comment: I just test it on my side and it won't revert to the default value. I opened the Entitlements.plist with Source Code editor and I use visual studio 2019 16.3.1.

Comment: Magic. I now create simple ios project, open Entitlements.plist file enable iCloud + key-value storage and in the source mode change 'iCloud Key-Value Store' property value, save changes. then close file tab and reopen it again. This property reverted to '$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)' value

Comment: I upload a sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/iCloud-xamarin.ios) and I changed the  'iCloud Key-Value Store' property value in the project. You can check it.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/o4w91o - screenshot  

iCloud Key-Value Store = $(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)

Comment: any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: also if this is important VS about https://prnt.sc/o4x7rw

Comment: Oh, my bad. I test it on VS for windows and the value can be changed. I just test it on VS for mac and I meet the same problem with you.

Comment: Maybe you known where i can create bug?

Comment: never-mind, already find and create

Comment: OK, follow the issue you created in Github and you will get support there.